# Laravel 5.5 global variable in template from service provider

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, service-provider

How can I get info about logged user in service provider? When I use this in my template {{ $test }} always return 0 but i'm 100% sure that im logged in. Or mybe you have better solution?

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Auth;
use View;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        if ($user !== null) {
            $walletsCount = $user->wallets()->count();
        } else {
            $walletsCount = 0;
        }
        View::share('test', $walletsCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: but you already have the user when you make Auth::user()

Comment: `Auth::user()` is already global therefore I don't quite understand your intentions...

Comment: when im using this in controller I don't have any problem. I want to have count of wallets in templates.

Comment: I still don't understand the intention here... It's almost like you're wanting a ComposerServiceProvider. Please clarify

Comment: you don't have Sessions until the session middleware has ran ... service provider @ boot is called super early in the lifecycle, well before the request gets to that middleware

Comment: @lagbox so how can I save my count? I have many controllers so i need to do this in one place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because auth functionality is not initialized yet when Laravel is loading service providers. One way to deal with it is to move the logic to the view:

```
{{ auth()->check() ? auth()->user()->wallets()->count() : 0 }}
```

Another way to go is using a view composer with closure:

```
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer('*', function($view) {
        $view->with('walletsCount', auth()->check() ? auth()->user()->wallets()->count() : 0);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have access to sessions this early in the request lifecycle, by default. The `web` group of middleware has a `StartSession` middleware which is responsible for actually starting and loading the session. The `Auth` system by default, `web` guard, uses sessions to store the user. So you don't have access to the session yet, so the user will return as `null`. The request hasn't even made it to that stack of middleware yet.

You could add a middleware to do this. Add the middleware to the end of your `web` stack. When this middleware gets ran the previous middleware in the stack have already loaded the session so you will have access to your authenticated user there.

If this is like a layout you need this variable for you could use a view composer instead. There are some options depending on exactly your need.